# El GameObject no avanza hacia adelante ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Al implementar las 3 primeras líneas de código (del método) no logro conseguir que mi GameObject avance. Las variables "myKeyDownH" y "myKeyDownV" son valores fijos que se activan al momento de presionar alguna tecla (A, S, D y W). Es decir, representan el plano cartesiano, en valores negativos o positivos. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

```
private Animator animator;
private Rigidbody rb;
private float speed = 5f;
private float myKeyDownH;
private float myKeyDownV;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Up");
        speed = 3;
        myKeyDownH = 0f;
        myKeyDownV = 3f;
        animator.SetTrigger("Fly");
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Right");
        myKeyDownH = 3f;
        myKeyDownV = 0f;
        animator.SetTrigger("Fly");
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Left");
        myKeyDownH = -3f;
        myKeyDownV = 0f;
        animator.SetTrigger("Fly");
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Down");
        myKeyDownH = 0f;
        myKeyDownV = -3f;
        animator.SetTrigger("Fly");
    }

    FixedUpdate();
}

void FixedUpdate() // a diferencia de "Update", está preparado para trabajar con físicas.
{
    var trans = transform.position;
    var currentTransform = new Vector3(myKeyDownH, myKeyDownV, trans.z);
    transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, currentTransform, Time.deltaTime); //interpolar entre dos puntos

    rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Collision")
    {
        print(other.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Bienvenido, el còdigo debe agregarse como texto por favor, te sugerimos tambièn revisar[ask], saludos.

Comment: Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento.